# Can't run utilities that use the network from a Windows Server 2008 DFS share

Tags: windows-server-2008, dfs

Under Windows Server 2008 I'm unable to run many utilities that use network resources.  This works just fine under Windows Server 2003.

For example:

- \\domain\dfs\tools$\bin\sendmail.exe ...
- \\domain\dfs\tools$\bin\psexec.exe ...
- echo %_metric% %_value% %_unixtime% | \\domain\dfs\bin\foo$\nc graphite.domain 2003 -w1

Reproducing and maintaining this folder on a large number of servers/vm's is not desirable.  Is there a way to allow Windows Server 2008 to run these tools?  If so, can this be enabled via GPO or in a fashion that can be scripted during automated builds?

Edit: The commands/tools do work just fine, when run from local drives.

Edit2: Wget example:

```
d:\scripts\helpers>z:\bin\wget http://www.google.com
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = z:/etc/wgetrc
--2011-04-11 00:32:15--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com... failed: Host not found.
z:\bin\wget: unable to resolve host address `www.google.com'
```

wget can neither use DNS to resolve the IP nor can it use HTTP if provided an IP directly.

Edit3: The problem seems to be tied to DFS/DFS shares.  Tools run correctly from other normal windows-server file-shares.  They also run correctly when run directly from the file-servers behind the DFS.  They only fail when we attempt to run them from the DFS UNC path or mapped drives.

Comment: I've given the answer to this one here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/378182/windows-7-blocks-network-access-to-network-installed-apps/627243#627243

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem but it was resolved when I disabled access-based enumeration for this namespace.

You may want to try the same.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault. We prefer answers that include some kind of explanation as to ***why*** they work, otherwise [your answer may make the problem go away, but it's not really helpful - it's Voodo System Administration](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/).  Can you explain *why* this worked?

Answer (score 0):

Add the remote share into IE's Trusted sites zone.

Comment: Tried that.  Added *.domain to local intranet, also tried trusted sites and with explicit server names.  Same results, exe runs, but can't open sockets/network resources.  DEP disabled, UAC disabled, domain,public, private firewall policies disabled.  Tools are on a DFS, tried to hit the file-servers behind that directly also.  No luck.

Comment: Try adding it in UNC format \\server\share

Comment: Tried UNC file:////\\server\share as well as a few other variants.  Still no go.

Comment: If you map a drive to the share, do the programs run?

Comment: The programs run, but again something is blocking outbound connectivity.  Wget runs, but is unable to connect out to do DNS lookups or HTTP calls.

Comment: Ok, put wget on a couple other servers and I'm able to execute the directly and correctly from those servers.  When I execute them directly file-shares on the servers in the DFS, it works correctly.  So it just seems to fail when using the DFS UNC path or DFS mapped drive.  Guess I need to learn a bit about DFS.